# Can't access mic in my laptop

Tags: sound, windows, microphone, ubuntu-drivers

I am using dual boot operating system (win8 + Ubuntu20.04) in HP Pavilion g4, I can't access microphone in any of the operating system. Earlier it was working fine, I am using an earphone with mic in it , and the mic is working fine in my phone. Earlier i faced same issue with my inbuilt-webcam but then i went to shop and he installed some drivers and it started working again.
I also changed my windows8 to win10 but still facing same issue, and can't access the mic even in live ubuntu. Please any one help

Comment: If the problems are both in Windows and Ubuntu you have a hardware problem not a Ubuntu problem. Time to go back to the shop I think.

Comment: no bro it happend same with the webcam, webcam doesn't work in either of the os, but the shopkeeper guy just fixed it with some driver updates.